# Hola tengo un problema quiero mostrar lo siguiente en angular y no lo logro

Tags: nodejs, angular

tengo lo siguiente y me devuelve un resultado en JSON.
Es una consulta a un DB Oracle, quiero mostrarlo con angular en una tabla, ¿cómo puedo hacerlo?

//servicio.js

```
constructor(public http: HttpClient) { }
getTodos(): Observable<any>{
  return this.http.get(`${this.apiURL}`);
```

//components

```
ngOnInit() {
this.apiService.getTodos()
.subscribe(
  (data) => { // Success
    this.data = data['Datos'];
    console.log(data)

  },
  (error) => {
    console.error(error);
```

//modelo de datos

```
export class Datos {

    name: string;
    GROUP_NUMBER: number;
    TOTAL_MB: number;
    FREE_MB:number;
    USABLE_FILE_MB:number;
    data: [];
}
```

//como debo construir el components html

Answer (score 0):

Para mostrar los valores obtenidos de un **"componente"** en el **"html"** puedes usar la directiva `*ngFor` como te muestro a continuación.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>name</td>
            <td>GROUP_NUMBER</td>
            <td>TOTAL_MB</td>
            <td>(..los demas campos)</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let da of data">
            <td>{{da.name}}</td>
            <td>{{da.GROUP_NUMBER}}</td>
            <td>{{da.TOTAL_MB}}</td>
            <td>(..los demas campos)</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

donde la variable `data` es la variable que usaste en tu **"componente"** para obtener todos los objectos en conjunto o el `array` de tu `json` y la variable `da` es una variable que obtendrá los objectos por bucle y permitirá visualizar los atributos de los objectos que deseas mostrar.
Para mas información puedes leer la documentación: https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf